# Atualizar campos com Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

## O problema

Estou fazendo uma requisição **Ajax** para retornar uns dados de uma tabela. Ele chega e entrar nessa função para começar o foreach das informações, mas duas delas estão se "perdendo" no caminho. Eu dei um alerte em `value['outras_atividades']` antes dele entrar no `if`, e ele mostrou o texto desse campo normalmente, mas foi entrar dentro do `if` que ele ficou como `undefined`, ou seja, não consigo preencher os campos de texto com esses valores.

## Meu Código

### Ajax

```
$('#verificaEntidade').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url : "retornaEntidade",
            data: $('#formVerifEnt').serialize(),
            success : function(msg){
                if(msg.status == 0) {
                    alert("O formulário dessa entidade ainda não foi preenchido !");
                }
                else {
                    msg.errorMsg.forEach(ShowResults);
                }
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                 alert("Erro no Processamento dos Dados. Entre em contato com o setor de Tecnologia e informe a mensagem abaixo:\n"+xhr.responseText);
            }
        });

    });
```

### Função para marcar campos do formulário

```
function ShowResults(value, index, ar) {
        var i = 0;

        /*Faz a verificação para atualizar os checkboxes das atividades realizadas*/
        if(value['codigo_atividade']) {
            for(i = 1; i <= 11; i++) {
                if(value['codigo_atividade'] == i) {
                    $('#atv'+ i).prop('checked', true);
                    if(value['codigo_atividade'] == 11) {
                        $('input[name=txtOutrasAtividades]').val(value['outras_atividades']);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /*Faz a verificação para atualizar os checkboxes dos públicos atendidos*/
        if(value['codigo_publico']) {
            for(i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
                if(value['codigo_publico'] == i) {
                    $('#pub'+ i).prop('checked', true);
                    if(value['codigo_publico'] == 9) {
                        $('input[name=txtOutrosPublicos]').val(value['outros_publicos']);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: O que dá `alert(typeof value['outras_atividades']);`?

Comment: Já pensou em adicionar em uma variável, depois no if chamar a variável?

valor = value['codigo_atividade']

Comment: @Vanderson Já fiz isso para fazer um teste, e o resultado foi o mesmo.

Comment: Já tentou o jQuery.proxy??
http://blog.dmatoso.com/2011/05/como-funciona-a-funcao-proxy-do-jquery/

Comment: @AllanRamos deu `undefined` antes do `if`? ou seja logo a seguir a `var i = 0;`?

Comment: @Sergio fiz o alert logo depois do var i = 0; e ele deu string, e dentro do if deu undefined

Comment: Ok. Esse erro não me faz muito sentido, o `if` não muda nada. O código da pergunta é exatamente o mesmo que usas? ou é uma versão simplificada e o erro talvez se perca no caminho?

Comment: @Sergio o código é esse exatamente, eu copiei e colei.

Comment: Coloca `console.log(JSON.stringify(value));` antes de `var i = 0;`. O que retorna?

Comment: Apareceu assim:

{"outras_atividades":"Outras Atividades","sem_atividades":"S"}

E na segunda linha.
{"codigo_atividade":11}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu erro é que você está manipulando o `msg.errorMsg.forEach(ShowResults);`

`msg.errorMsg.forEach` não vai passar para sua função se ele não retornar erro. Você deve apenas chamar a função `ShowResults(value)`, contendo o resultado do seu json. Assim manipulará do lado da função que invocou o valor passado.

O errorMsg para o formulário com erro. Se não há erro na posição a mensagem é 
`undefined`